# Assert a method is called with an object as agument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I want to test a function which calls some method of an object. All I need is to test whether that object's method is getting called with an object as argument. Scenario is something like this:

```
    def foo(settings):
        handler = somemodule.Somehandler()
        if settings.get('key') is True:
            handler.some_method(Formatter('foo'))
        return handler
```

I want to test if `some_method` is called with `Formatter` object as argument
My test looks like this:

```
    @patch('somemodule.Somehandler')
    def test_foo(self, mockhandler):
        mockhandler.some_method = MagickMock()
        Formatter = MagickMock()
        foo(mysettings)
        mockhandler.some_method.assert_called_with(Formatter('foo'))
```

But assertion is failing with error:
E   AssertionError: Expected call: some_method()
E           Not called

Comment: Did you set `key` to `True` in `mysettings`? Also, there's no need for `is`; just use `if settings.get('key')`.

Comment: Yes, reading from `settings` is no problem. I've checked that the execution is going to the part of code I want to test. So basically it is going at the point where `some_method` is getting called. At this point I expect my mocked version of `some_method` should get called (that is what I want to achieve), but that is not happening here.